# Cancel a particular coroutine of a specific ViewHolder inside onViewDetachedFromWindow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines

(Edited Question....)
I am developing a chat application and there is a specific API so some things i must implement them with a specific way. For example (and the case that i have a problem...)

When i have to display an Image the API says that i have to split the Image in small chunks and store them as a message with a byteArray content. There is also a header message that its body is the messageIds of the fileChunks. So in the RecyclerView inside the onBindViewHolder, when i see a header file message (msgType == 1) then i start a coroutine to fetch the chunkFile messages by the ids, construct the File and then switch to the MainDispatcher, and so the Image with Glide using a BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray. The code is shown below

```
messageItem.message?.msgType == MSG_TYPE_FILE -> {
     holder.sntBody.text = "Loading file"

     val fileInfo = Gson().fromJson(URLDecoder.decode(messageItem.message?.body, "UTF-8"), FileInformation::class.java)

     job = chatRoomAdapterScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // i get the messageIds of the chunks from Header message
    val segSequence = fileInfo.seg.split(",").map { it.toLong() }

    // i get the fileChunks from Database
    val fileChunks = AppDatabase.invoke(mContext).messageDao().getMessageById(segSequence)
    val compactFile = ByteArrayOutputStream()

    // Reconstruct the file
    for (chunk in fileChunks)
        compactFile.write(Base64.decode(chunk.fileBody, Base64.DEFAULT))

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val bitmapOptions = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
                inSampleSize = 8
            }

        Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap()
            .load(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(compactFile.toByteArray(), 0, compactFile.size(), bitmapOptions)!!)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                 override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    holder.sntImageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
                    holder.sntImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                 }
             })
              holder.sntBody.text = fileInfo.filename
       }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i scroll fast the image that is supposed to be loaded in an item appears in another item. My first guess is that the Coroutine that started from a specific item didnt complete as soon as the item was recycled so when the coroutine finished it had a reference to a new item, so i added the
holder.itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener method as some people commented. However i didn't work.
Is there any idea of why that may happens and if there is a better implementation of the proccess according to the specific API...?

Comment: I suggest you get that coroutine out of the Adapter and code in the presenter/viewmodel and after that you may render it.

Comment: Best solution is moving the coroutine out of the adapter. But if you want to trade of with performance and recycling then you can disable it with:
 holder.setIsRecyclable(false)

Comment: Is there a simple code example that i get from you guys becasue i am a begginer in Coroutines and stuff...? Thnx a lot by the way!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use `View.OnAttachStateChangeListener` for it:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder() {
    if(messageType == TYPE_FILE) {
        val job = chatRoomAdapterScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val fileChunks = AppDatabase.invoke(MyApplication.instance).messageDao()
                .getMessageByMessageId(segSequence)
            // do some heacy work with the fileChunks
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                // holder set up
            }
        }
        holder.itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {
                view.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
                job.cancel()
            }

            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(p0: View?) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn t know that technique. I will give it a try and let you know..! Thank you my friend